# No sound after update on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, updates, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

As the title says, my sound has gone missing after an update with `update-manager`. I have found the solution before, but then had to reinstall Ubuntu. It can't even detect my audio card. Here is a screenshot of the sound settings.
[image: Sound Settings screenshot]

I have tried every single thing, including `killall pulseaudio`, updating the sound drivers, and removing the `alsa` plugins. This all happened after I updated through `update-manager` and I was wondering if I could rollback to stock without losing any data.

Note: This is **not** a duplicate, I have tried (I'm pretty sure) every single possible solution.

Comment: I've got exactly the same issue with the same version of Ubuntu. It's a shame :/

Comment: can you please post the output of `aplay -l` and the contents of `~/.config/pulse`?